# Creating a solution template for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates

Im trying to create a solution template following this [guide](https://www.jayway.com/2015/03/13/visual-studio-how-to-create-a-solution-template-with-multiple-projects/) . I was able to create the solution template with a class library, console app and web app.

Here is the content of `Root.vstemplate`:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Solution Template</Name>
    <Description>Test solution template</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>Solution Template</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="ClassLibrary1">
                ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="ConsoleApplication1">
                ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="WebApplication1">
                WebApplication1\WebApplication1.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

**The problem now :**
The generated project folders are not in the root folder of the solution, instead they are generated in a subfolder with solution name. this prevent the solution from ***restoring nuget packages***. moving manually the projects folders to the solution root folder and changing manually the .sln file fixes this issue, but still, this should be done automatically !
Is there any way to change the Root.vstemplate in order to get a working solution  with all project folders in the root folder ?